# HTML Background changes to current image

Tags: javascript, html

I am relatively new to coding. I downloaded a html template that is a timeline that I want to use for a project I am busy with. I am not using this as a website or to sell it or anything it is merely educational. I know how to edit the html and change it to my own words and add images etc. My problem is, I think, with the javascript. So what happens is,when you scroll on the timeline and it gets to an image the background changes to the active image and so it changes to every different image on the timestamps.

When i add new html code to essentially add more timestamps to the timeline the new timestamps image does not appear as the background. It seems as if it has a set length. I am completely clueless when it comes to javascript and would really appreciate it if someone could assist me with this. Here is the js file:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.timeline = function() {
    var selectors = {
      id: $(this),
      item: $(this).find(".timeline-item"),
      activeClass: "timeline-item--active",
      img: ".timeline__img"
    };
    selectors.item.eq(0).addClass(selectors.activeClass);
    selectors.id.css("background-image", "url(" + selectors.item.first().find(selectors.img).attr("src") + ")");

    var itemLength = selectors.item.length;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var max, min;
      var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
      selectors.item.each(function(i) {
        min = $(this).offset().top;
        max = ($(this).height() + $(this).offset().top);
        var that = $(this)
        if (i == itemLength - 2 && pos > min + $(this).height() / 2) {
          selectors.item.removeClass(selectors.activeClass);
          selectors.id.css("background-image", "url(" + selectors.item.last().find(selectors.img).attr('src') + ")");
          selectors.item.last().addClass(selectors.activeClass)
        } else if (pos <= max - 40 && pos >= min) {
            selectors.id.css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).find(selectors.img).attr('src') + ")");
            selectors.item.removeClass(selectors.activeClass);
            $(this).addClass(selectors.activeClass);
          }

      });
    });

  }
})(jQuery);
$("#timeline-1").timeline();
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="timeline-item" data-text="Text">
  <div class="timeline__content"><img class="timeline__img" src="BG1.jpg"/>
    <h2 class="timeline__content-title">
      7 October 9:53 PM</h2>
    <p class="timeline__content-desc">Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you including the .timeline-item class to the images you are adding? It would be helpful to see some HTML as well

Comment: @fraggley This is the html code used per timestamp: <div class="timeline-item" data-text="Text">
      <div class="timeline__content"><img class="timeline__img" src="BG1.jpg"/>
        <h2 class="timeline__content-title"> 7 October 9:53 PM</h2>
        <p class="timeline__content-desc"> Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: put the HTML and any other future code into the question itself. It's messy to say the very least looking at in the comment section, and people who jump into this question will have to look back and forth between the question and the comment section for code. That's not ideal at all.

Comment: If there is no problem in correlation with the HTML, then you should look at these statements, and what's inside them. `if (i == itemLength - 2 && pos > min + $(this).height() / 2)`, `else if (pos <= max - 40 && pos >= min)`. They control when your element gets the active class and when it's removed again.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the advice, it was my first post so I did not quite know how it all works. I will make sure to follow your advice. In regard to the statements, I honestly don't know whats going on there. I will try and figure it out then. Thanks a lot!